# Get value from user meta field Wordpress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

To create a new field I have added the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'add_vat_billing_field', 1 );

function add_vat_billing_field( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['kvk_number'] = array(
        'label'         => 'Btw-nummer',
        'placeholder'   => 'Btw-nummer',
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

In some other code this field is displayed using the following code:

```
<?php foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ) : ?>
    // The problem probably lies here in the "$key => $field" 
    <?php 
        // Make sure when "Guest" is selected the form fields are emptied
        if ( empty( $_POST['one_page_customer_user'] ) )
            $val = '';
        // Or if the user has no billing info leave fields empty
        else if ( !empty( $_POST['one_page_customer_user'] ) && false == get_user_meta( absint( $_POST['one_page_customer_user'] ), 'billing_first_name', true ) )
            $val = '';
        else 
            $val = $checkout->get_value( $key );

        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $val ); 
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Even though the user has a meta field value stored in `kvk_number` it won't show up while the other fields are perfectly filled in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

It turns out that `$val = $checkout->get_value( $key );` is trying to return a value for a field by the value of that field. `$key` here is already the value. But instead of returning the value, it is now looking for a field with the value of that field as name.

**Edit 2**

```
function example_callback( $input ) {
    return $input;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'example_callback' );
```

This will do for now.. Gonna have to make this more safe now as it completely ruins the original `get_value( $key );` function.